# I have a problem about rtl my page in css, can anyone help me?

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I face the problem of creating a rtl(right to left) stylesheet when I want to rtl Elements include `<i>` tag beside any texts or spans. 
For example, there is something like this:
There are three elements inside this  tag:

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="sl sl-icon-docs"></i>Requests<span>2</span></a></li>
```

First image: this is showing my theme before rtl:
[image: First image: this is showing my theme before rtl]

1. An icon located before the main button title
2. Button title
3. a tag for showing number of new requests as a label.

an order should reverse and show all items inside `<a>` tag from the right, it means from the right we will have 1.icon  2.title 3.label

Second image: rtl by using `flex-direction: row-reverse;` on main content:
[image: Second image: rtl by using flex-direction: row-reverse; on main content]

I applied `direction: rtl;` to the `<li>` element but nothing works, you can see the changes on second image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the content of the link `<a>` by using `flex-direction: row-reverse` on it :

```css
.reverse{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="sl sl-icon-docs">Icon</i>Requests<span>2</span></a></li> 
     <li><a href="#" class="reverse"><i class="sl sl-icon-docs">Icon</i>Requests<span>2</span></a></li> 
</ul>

<!-- Other examples -->

<a class="reverse">(1) Click me<i class="sl sl-icon-docs">(2) icon</i></a>
<h3 class="reverse">(1) Title example<i class="sl sl-icon-docs">(2) icon</i></h3>
```

Comment: @ user10980566 
Thanks it works on my example, but on other states like below not working:
`<a class="reverse">Click me<i class="sl sl-icon-docs">icon</i></a>`

or :

`<h3>Title example<i class="sl sl-icon-docs">icon</i></h3>`
I also try to insert `<h3>` tag into `<div>` but not working again.

Comment: It should work on your examples too... Adding the `flex-direction: reverse` on any parent containing multiple direct childs should reverse them. You may check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) for more examples.

Comment: the problem is there is only one child inside this tag, the text is belong to its `<a>` tag.

Comment: So you need to include the elements you want to reverse into separated childs elements (span, div...) and use a single parent to contain them all. If my edit is not solving your problem, can you edit your own post including the whole new code that is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

RTL works but not on the `<span>` part. If you can change span into a division then it'll work.

Else you can use `flex-direction: row-reverse` after making `<li>` a `display:flex`

Here's my code:

```css
#rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}

#flex>a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

li {
  background: red;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 3em;
  margin: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10em;
  padding: 0 0.7em;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="normal">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/30?image=0" />Normal <span>1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li id="rtl">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/30?image=0" />RTL <span>2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li id="flex">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/30?image=0" />Row-Reverse <span>3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The code needs some polishing but I think you've got what you were looking for.

I hope this helps.

Peace